# lightslider goToSlide() no animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am using the following lightslider: http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/

If I am going to call:

```
<script>
    var slider = $("#lightSlider").lightSlider({//myoptions});
    var x = //Any number;
    slider.goToSlide(x);
</script>
```

The slider is going to the correct slide. But the slider is going to slide to the picture. So if I do have 100 pictures and I am going to picture 99, the slider is sliding through all picture. This looks ugly.

How can I do it, that the slider is going directly to picture 99 without any animation. Just open picture 99 and the click usual on next/prev with sliding effect.

Thanks!

Craphunter

Comment: I'm surprised this does anything at all since you have commented out part of the function. .lightSlider({`//myoptions});` I'm sure that would cause syntax errors...

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps try setting the `slideMove` to the number you want before   `slider.goToSlide(x);`
Moreover, you could turn off the animations before moving to the slide.